# Adding a Filter to Table With Parent/Child Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I found a very simple way to add a filter to a table with the following code:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () {
    var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
    $('.searchable').hide();
    $('.searchable').filter(function () {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
});
```

As of right now the filter is only looking at rows that have the class "searchable". This class consists of all the parent rows. All of the child rows have a class "tablesorter-childRow". How can I get my filter function work with parent and child rows. If that parent makes it though the filter then the child rows should as well. If the parent row has child rows showing before the filter then the child rows should be showing after the filter and vice verse.

Here is some html that is generated:

```
<tr class="searchable danger tablesorter-hasChildRow" role="row" style="border-top-style: solid;">
   <td style="text-align: center;">
      <input id="items_0__SuggestedQty" name="items[0].SuggestedQty" type="hidden" value="28">
      <input class="suggested" id="items_0__UseSuggestedQty" name="items[0].UseSuggestedQty" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;float:right;" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="items[0].UseSuggestedQty" type="hidden" value="false">
      <label for="Qty_28__" style="margin-top:6px;margin-right: 5px;float:right">Qty(28) </label>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">
      <input id="items_0__Quantity" name="items[0].Quantity" type="hidden" value="1000">
      <input checked="checked" class="override" id="items_0__Override" name="items[0].Override" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;float:right;" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="items[0].Override" type="hidden" value="false">
      <label for="Qty_1000__" style="margin-top:6px;margin-right: 5px;float:right;">Qty(1000) </label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__LineNo" name="items[0].LineNo" type="hidden" value="3">
      3
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__PartNo" name="items[0].PartNo" type="hidden" value="06756275">
      06756275
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__Description" name="items[0].Description" type="hidden" value="ROLLER-.187 X 1.250 LG">
      ROLLER-.187 X 1.250 LG
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__Cost" name="items[0].Cost" type="hidden" value="0.48">
      0.48
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__ExtendedCost" name="items[0].ExtendedCost" type="hidden" value="">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__NetAvailability" name="items[0].NetAvailability" type="hidden" value="256">
      256
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__AdjustedNetAvailability" name="items[0].AdjustedNetAvailability" type="hidden" value="228">
      228
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__UsageRate" name="items[0].UsageRate" type="hidden" value="71.25">
      71.25
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__PriorYearUsage" name="items[0].PriorYearUsage" type="hidden" value="1774">
      1774
   </td>
   <td>
      <input id="items_0__UsageRatio" name="items[0].UsageRatio" type="hidden" value="3.59">
      3.59
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="" class="tablesorter-childRow danger" role="row">
   <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">
      Reason
   </td>
   <td colspan="12">
      <select class="form-control" id="items_0__ReasonCode" name="items[0].ReasonCode" style="max-width: none; width: auto">
         <option value="1">Emerging Demand – New item with demand expected to grow</option>
         <option value="2">Quantity Pack Item – Must buy factory minimum</option>
         <option value="3">Bulk Buy – Large purchase for distribution</option>
         <option value="4">Lead Time – Longer than typical lead time</option>
         <option value="5">Service Request – Service Dept. requested item for stock</option>
         <option selected="selected" value="6">Sales Request – Sales Dept. requesting item for stock</option>
         <option value="7"></option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="border-bottom-style: solid;" class="tablesorter-childRow danger" role="row">
   <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">
      Comments
   </td>
   <td colspan="12">
      <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="items_0__Comments" name="items[0].Comments" rows="2">testing</textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the parent/child row markup?

Comment: I added some html so you can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic approach is going to be using `nextUntil` and `prevUntil`. Here is an example that probably won't work as is, but demonstrates the basic idea:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () {
    var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
    var $rows = $('.searchable, .tablesorter-childRow').hide();       
    var $filtered = $rows.filter(function () {
        return rex.test($(this).text());
    });

    $filtered.each(function($match){
      // parent row, show all the children until the next parent row is reached
      if($match.hasClass('.searchable')){
         $match.nextUntil('.tablesorter-childRow', '.searchable').show();
      } else {
         // child row, this will need work, show subsequent children,
         // show previous children, show previous parent
         var show = [];
         show.push($match.nextUntil('.tablesorter-childRow', '.searchable'));
         show.push($match.prevUntil('.tablesorter-childRow', '.searchable'));
         show.push($match.prev('.searchable'));

         $(show).show();
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: When I added it and type in the filter box. There is no matches for everything that i type.